# Selecting values from one column based on values in adjacent column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble selecting values from one column based on values in another in a pandas df.
Simulated data:

```
n = 10000
userid = list(map(lambda x: int(x), np.random.sample(n)*100000))
useramount = list(map(lambda x: round(x,2), np.random.sample(n)*100))
transferdate = pd.to_datetime(np.random.choice(pd.date_range(start = '03/13/1994', periods = n), n).tolist())

transfers = pd.DataFrame({'userid':userid,
             'useramount':useramount,
             'transferdate':transferdate})

v = transfers.userid.value_counts()

transfers = transfers[transfers.userid.isin(v.index[v>1])]

grouped = transfers.groupby(['userid','useramount'],as_index=False).agg({'transferdate':'min'})
```

Grouped looks like this:

```
    userid  useramount  transferdate
0   350 13.01   2013-09-30
1   350 46.98   2003-02-28
2   431 25.88   1998-01-31
3   431 97.76   1999-08-15
```

I'd like to subset every userid and useramount where the date is the earlier of the two so ideally my outcome would look like:

```
    userid  useramount  transferdate
1   350 46.98   2003-02-28
2   431 25.88   1998-01-31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
#grouped['transferdate']=pd.to_datetime(grouped['transferdate']) if necessary
grouped.sort_values(['userid','transferdate']).drop_duplicates('userid')
#   userid  useramount transferdate
#1     350       46.98   2003-02-28
#2     431       25.88   1998-01-31
```

or [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
grouped.sort_values(['userid','transferdate']).groupby('userid',as_index=False).first()
```

Comment: the .first() method doesn't quite work because it will return rows that have lower index but not necessarily earliest date, sort_values with drop_duplicates, however, works fine including when tested against an SQL query designed to do the same thing. Thanks ansev!